# Erro na instalação do Composer: 'não foi possivel encontrar o módulo especificado (php_intl.dll)'

Tags: php, composer, instalador, wamp

Estou usando windows 10, 64 bits. Ao tentar instalar o composer, exibe o erro:

[image]

O php que está sendo indicado na instalação do composer é o do Wamp (localizado em c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10), e eu já verifiquei que a dll php_intl está lá. Já tentei alterar o php.ini, na linha extension_dir, colocando o caminho completo, mas mesmo assim encontro esse problema. Se alguém puder me dar uma mãosinha por favor...

Answer (score 1):

Descomentar  a extensão no seu **php.ini** apenas já resolveria o problema, após isso você deve reiniciar o serviço do Wamp. Caso não funcione , provavelmente será necessário baixar e instalar essa extensão.

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem pode ser o problema:

> A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

A configuração do `extension_dir` **pode talvez** estar errada no teu php.ini, o que esta afetando carregar as extensões.

Se as extensões estiverem de fato dentro da pasta `c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext`, então o caminho no `php.ini` deve ser

```
extension_dir="ext"
```

Ou:

```
extension_dir="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext"
```

Se ainda falhar é porque de alguma maneira o `php_intl.dll` não existe dentro da pasta ou foi movido para `c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/` ou esta usando uma versão incorreta da `.dll` (eu mesmo tive alguns problemas com extensões do PHP7 no Windows)

Se suas dlls estiverem fora da pasta `ext` você pode então ajustar o `extension_dir` para:

```
extension_dir="."
```

Ou:

```
extension_dir="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10"
```

Ou então mover todos arquivos com prefixo `php_` para dentro da pasta `ext`